# What is a Top-most class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

So tha main problem is to understand the class hierarchy of Java.
We need to give an answer to this question:
*"Explain whether in Java there is one single class hierarchy (with a single     class at the top) or there are many class hierarchies (each with its own top-most class). Explain what consequences this has."*

I have no idea about how to answer this question..

Comment: What about `Object`?

Comment: [The class `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)

Comment: Is it just me or is there a pattern developing in the comments and answers?

Comment: Why -1?? Sometimes i don't really understand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) JavaDoc:

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

**Edit:** Also take a look at [the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2).

Comment: And what about the consequences? i'm not really getting this part:"All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class."

Comment: I don't kow what 'consequences' your teacher is talking about. Please tell us more about what he may have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

All objects in java inherit from [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its the [Object class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2).

> The class Object is a superclass (§8.1.4) of all other classes.

Also check this [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html):

> The Object class, in the java.lang package, sits at the top of the
>   class hierarchy tree. Every class is a descendant, direct or indirect,
>   of the Object class. Every class you use or write inherits the
>   instance methods of Object.

Answer (score 0):

The `Object` class is mother of all java classes. 
You can verify the same programmatically. 
You will get `null` in the code below for `Super Class` of `Object`

> `Object.class.getSuperclass(); // returns null`

The above test can be done for any other class similarly.

Answer (score 0):

It is the **Object** Class. Every class is directly or indirectly descendant of Object class which is in java.lang package. Unlike any other parent/child class it doesn't require extends key word to inherit. It's implicit by nature where as you can write explicitly. Java compiler doesn't deny it.

You can use/call methods of object class from any other class and at the same time you can overwrite them to implement in your way.